# How to select a row by many to many relation connection?

Tags: mysql, node.js, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

Here are my type-orm entities:

```js
@Entity()
export class Conversation {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @ManyToMany((type) => User, (user) => user.conversations)
  attendees: User[];
}
```

```js
@Entity()
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @ManyToMany((type) => Conversation, (conversation) => conversation.attendees)
  @JoinTable()
  conversations: Conversation[];
}
```

Having two different user IDs, I want to select a single conversation entity, which contains both of those users as `attendees`.
What I managed to get so far are the conversations of one user:

```js
const conversationsUsers = await conversationRepository
  .createQueryBuilder("c")
  .innerJoinAndSelect("c.attendees", "user", "user.id = :authorId", { authorId })
  .getMany();
```

Being far from becoming SQL expert, I think I should create another `JOIN` with `users` table (with an alias for e.g. `user.id` => `attende_id`, but have no idea how to approach this.

Thanks in advance for any thoughts :)

Comment: if you have many-to-many relation you should add 3rd table - if you do a bit of googling, you should find some hints,

Comment: I think `type-orm` got me covered on this - it created tables like `user`, `conversation` and `user_conversations_conversation`. Do you suggest that better approach is to create it manually anyway?